# What are the algebras for the laxification 2-monad?

Tags: ct.category-theory, higher-category-theory, monads, 2-categories

Let $C$ be a small 2-category. Let $[C , Cat]$ denote the 2-category of strict functors to $Cat$, 2-natural transformations, and modifications. Let $[[ C, Cat ]]$ denote the 2-category with the same objects, but lax natural transformations and lax modifications for 1-and 2-morphisms. There is a natural inclusion 2-functor $i_C: [C, Cat] \to [[C, Cat ]]$.

I have mostly convinced myself that $i_C$ has both a left and a right 2-adjoint, and that $i_C$ identifies $[[C, Cat ]]$ as both the Kleisli 2-category for the resulting "laxification" 2-monad on $[C, Cat]$ and as the coKleisli 2-category for the resulting 2-comonad on $[C, Cat]$.

**Question:** What is the 2-category of algebras for this "laxification" 2-monad on $[C, Cat]$? (These should form an equivalent 2-category to the coalgebras for the adjoint 2-comonad.)

Note that when $C = [1]$ is the arrow category, the 2-monad is $(E \xrightarrow p B) \mapsto (p \downarrow B \to B)$; the algebras for this 2-monad are the Grothendieck opfibrations in $Cat$. Dually, when $C = [1]$, the comonad is $(E \xrightarrow p B) \mapsto (E \to collage(p))$, and   the coalgebras for this 2-comonad are the co-opfibrations.

In this discussion, we should be able to replace $Cat$ with any complete and cocomplete 2-category $\mathcal K$.

Comment: Ah... (1) the classical way to think about this story is to think of $[C,Cat]$ as the algebras for a 2-monad on $[Ob C, Cat]$, whose algebras-with-lax-morphisms are $[[C,Cat]]$. (2) There's a natural guess for the answer to the question -- it should be the 2-category of lax algebras for this same 2-monad. (3) This should be some kind of 2-category of lax functors $C \to Cat$ (perhaps _normal_ lax functors?). (4) Unfortunately, I haven't been able to confirm any of this in e.g. Blackwell-Kelly-Power...

Comment: Have you tried thinking about it from a Grothendieck construction perspective ? Namely, ask the same question about $coCart_C$ and the full subcategory of $Cat_{/C}$ spanned by coCartesian fibrations ? In this case $i_C$ is also just the inclusion, and its left adjoint has been computed explicitly in these terms, so maybe you can do something?

Comment: A comment about terminology - is there any particular reason for not calling it the relaxation monad?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think that the algebras for this 2-monad coincide with the coalgebras for the 2-comonad.  If the adjoints are $L\dashv i \dashv R$, then the comonad is $L i$ while the monad is $R i$, and $L i \dashv R i$, but the result about algebras and coalgebras coinciding applies when a comonad is *right* adjoint to a monad.

I don't know anything about the algebras for the 2-monad, but Steve Lack and I used the coalgebras for the 2-comonad in [Enhanced 2-categories and limits for lax morphisms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1104.2111): they are the weights $J$ such that $J$-weighted limits lift to the category of algebras and colax morphisms for any 2-monad.  (We spent most of the paper on a corresponding $\mathscr{F}$-categorical version that also detects strictness of maps into the limit, but the 2-categorical version is discussed in section 6.4.)

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look! That's a really good point that the adjointness is in the wrong direction for the algebras and coalgebras to automatically coincide. And I suppose in the example I gave where $C = [1]$ is the arrow category, although the opfibrations and co-opfibrations coincide in $Cat$, they don't coincide in more general 2-categories $\mathcal K$. I wonder what's going on to make them coincide in this case...